# Update with inner join, update 2 columns from both tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

This is my query in sql server 2008 -

```
    UPDATE a 
       SET a.col2 = 'new', 
           a.col3 = 'www.google.com', 
           b.col1 = '10'
      FROM table a 
INNER JOIN table b ON a.col1 = b.col1 
     WHERE a.col1 = 7
```

It crashes stating "Invalid column name b.col1."

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 9):

You can only update 1 table at a time

you need to issue 2 update statements

```
UPDATE a SET a.col2='new', a.col3='www.google.com'
FROM tablea a INNER JOIN tableb  b ON a.col1 = b.col1
WHERE a.col1=7

UPDATE b SET b.col1='10' 
FROM tablea a INNER JOIN tableb b ON a.col1 = b.col1
WHERE a.col1=7
```

Answer (score 4):

From looking at your query a little closer, you have b.Col1 in the UPDATE statement. this is incorrect

```
UPDATE  a
SET a.col2='new', 
        a.col3='www.google.com', 
        b.col1='10' 
FROM    @table a INNER JOIN 
        @table b ON a.col1 = b.col1 
WHERE   a.col1=7
```

From [UPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662(SQL.80).aspx) you can only update 1 table at a time

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I said. *From UPDATE you can only update 1 table at a time*

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is "Update A", and you're trying to update a column in table B.  You might want to create a view containing the columns in tables A and B, and update that.  You could also create triggers for table A - perhaps one that will update the appropriate jointed column in table B.

Comment: even with a view you can only update 1 base table at a time..unless you add a trigger to the view

Answer (score 0):

For updating a column value in 1 table based on a condition on another column in second table, this worked for me:

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET TableA.col1 = 'dummyVal'
WHERE TableA .ACCID IN (SELECT ACCID FROM TableB WHERE TableB.PRODID LIKE 'XYZ')
```